# How can play HLS-(Http Live Streaming) in WindowsForm using C#?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, http-live-streaming

I want to play and HLS on line inside WindowsForm in one of my prime Desktop Application, which is built on .NET by using C#. Please if any one have any clue please help me?

Comment: We are talking about this -> [RFC8216](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8216), right?

Answer (score 2):

Use VLC media player and Its API , This supports online streaming of videos and also live streaming. This could be downloaded from NugetPackage Manager directly.

also you can use [Microsoft Media Platform: Player Framework](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=smf)